# Problem with scroll view and layout group

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, scrollview

I have inventory with slots you can scroll through from top to bottom.
You can scroll within a Rectangle named "content".
But the rectangle doesn't automatically scale it's size by the slot count so I added a Horizontal Layout Group to the Viewport and checked "Control Child Size" which does make the rectangle be as big as there are slots.
The issue is that I can't scroll anymore with the layout group active

I don't know if it helps much but here's the hierachy of the [inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poVo1.png)

Comment: Maybe [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861736/7111561) fits for you as well

Answer (score 0):

To automatically adjust size of scroll view. Assuming it is horizontal layout.

1. Add Layout group to arrange slots (Horizontal Layout group) to content GO.
2. Don't Use control child size on viewport use layout group on contents window.
3. Add content Size fitter too (to the content GO).
   That's all you need for dynamic auto resizable scroll view